# Building friendship relatationship in mysql

Tags: database-design, performance

I am creating friendship between user A and user B. So far my table looks like this:

```
friendship_request
| key:send_user | key:recv_user | sent |

friendship_request_history
| send_user | recv_user | sent | resolved_date | accepted | senderCanceled |

friendship
| key:user_1 | key:user_2 | date |
```

And when user `0` is friend with user `1` i put row for both sides:

```
| 0 | 1 | date |
| 1 | 0 | date |
```

However this requires additional space, when there are lots of user with friends.

Are there any better solutions, where i won't have to keep 2 rows for 1 friendship (e.g from both of sides )?

I could create just one row:

```
| 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 |
```

But here for example, if i wanted to insert new friendship for example for uses `0` and `1`, and i would do this on `1` side -> so row would looks like:

```
| 1 | 0 |
```

I would first have to check if record `| 1 | 0 |` or `| 0 | 1 |` exists in databse, otherwise i could have duplicate. If would insert 2 rows ( for both sides ) i could just insert the row and catch Exception for duplicate entry.

Are there any tricks for this? THanks for help!